# Given that $m \le n!$, what's a good lower bound for $n$ as a function of $m$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers with $m \le n! := n(n-1)\ldots(2)(1)$.

**Question 1:** What's a good lower bound for $n$ as a function of $m$ ?

For example, it's easy to see that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log m\le \log n! = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \log k \overset{\text{J.I.}}{\le} \left(\sum_{1\le k\le n}1\right)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{1\le k\le n}k}{\sum_{1\le k \le n}1}\right) = n \log\left( \frac{n + 1}{2}\right) \ll n^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
and so we must have $n \gg (\log m)^{1/2}$. Can one do much better than this ?

**Question 2:**
Define $\log^1 m = \log m$, $\log^2 m = \log \log m$, $\log^3 m = \log \log \log m$, etc. Does there exist an integer $k \ge 2$ and real numbers $a, u, v$ with $a, u > 0$, all independent of $m$, such that
$$n \ge h_{a, u, k, v}(m) := a + u \log m/ (\log^k m)^v$$
for sufficiently large $m$ ?

**N.B.:** Ideally, we'd want $a$, $u$, and $k$ to be "big", and $v$ to be "small".

## Update

The [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1938135/168758) solves the 2nd problem (and therefore both problems!) by showing that

If $e^e < m \le n!$, then $n \ge h_{0, 1, 2, 1}(m) = \log m/\log^2 m$.

Comment: Of course, I know about stirling's formula. How does this answer my question. Did you even read the question to the end ?

Comment: Well, for any $\epsilon>0$, for large enough $n$, you know that $n\log n\le n^{1+\epsilon}$, so for large $m$ it seems that $n\ge (\log m)^{1/(1+\epsilon)}$.

Comment: Might help: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function

Comment: Thanks, Ted! I also thought the bound $n\log n \le n^2$ was very loose, but couldn't find a way to avoid it for small $n$. Indeed, we seek a lower bound for $n$, so I find the argument "for $n$ large enough" troublesome / cyclic. Maybe not ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Claim**: if $n!\ge m > e^e$, then $n \ge \displaystyle\frac{\log m}{\log\log m}$.

Proof: We prove the contrapositive: Suppose that $m>e^e$ and $n < \frac{\log m}{\log\log m}$. Then
$$
n! \le  n^n < \bigg( \frac{\log m}{\log\log m} \bigg)^{(\log m)/\log\log m} < (\log m)^{(\log m)/\log\log m} = m.
$$

This lower bound is essentially best possible, in that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there are integers $m,n$ satisfying both $n!\ge m$ and $n < (1+\varepsilon) \frac{\log m}{\log\log m}$. One could get a second-order term with a little more work.

Comment: YES! Incredible! I felt something like this had to be true, but didn't quite know how to start. This solves my **Question 2**, and supplies $k=2$ and $u=v=1$. Thanks again!